# TypeError: $(...).bootstrapValidator is not a function , it does load the ContactUs.js file, but it's not able to find the function

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, bootstrapvalidator

As the Code is given and it is not able to find the function. I have tried several changes but still get the Error the sequence is also correct. The head part is at the top script and the other environment  development is at the bottom of the code between the `<body>` section.

```
<head>       
        <meta charset="utf-8" />
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
        <title>About Us-Azure Solutionz</title>

        <environment names="Development">
            <link rel="stylesheet" href="~/lib/bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.css" />
            <link rel="stylesheet" href="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery.bootstrapvalidator/0.5.3/css/boots‌​trapValidator.css"/>

            <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/ContactUs.css" />
            <link rel="stylesheet" href="~/css/site.css" />
             <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/NavbarButton.css"/>
            <link rel="stylesheet"  href="css/AboutUs.css"/>

              <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/Footer.css"/>
        </environment>
        <environment names="Staging,Production">
            <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://ajax.aspnetcdn.com/ajax/bootstrap/3.3.5/css/bootstrap.min.css"
                  asp-fallback-href="~/lib/bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css"
                  asp-fallback-test-class="sr-only" asp-fallback-test-property="position" asp-fallback-test-value="absolute" />
            <link rel="stylesheet" href="~/css/site.min.css" asp-append-version="true"/>
        </environment>

    </head>
<environment names="Development">
            <script src="~/lib/jquery/dist/jquery.js"></script>
            <script src="~/lib/bootstrap/dist/js/bootstrap.js"></script>
            <script src="~/js/site.js" asp-append-version="true"></script>
        </environment>
        <environment names="Staging,Production">
            <script src="https://ajax.aspnetcdn.com/ajax/jquery/jquery-2.1.4.min.js"
                    asp-fallback-src="~/lib/jquery/dist/jquery.min.js"
                    asp-fallback-test="window.jQuery">
            </script>
            <script type="text/javascript" src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.0/jquery.js"></script>
            <script src="https://ajax.aspnetcdn.com/ajax/bootstrap/3.3.5/bootstrap.min.js"
                    asp-fallback-src="~/lib/bootstrap/dist/js/bootstrap.min.js"
                    asp-fallback-test="window.jQuery && window.jQuery.fn && window.jQuery.fn.modal">
            </script>
            <script type="text/javascript" src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery.bootstrapvalidator/0.5.3/js/bootstr‌​apValidator.js"></script>
            <script src="js/ContactUs.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
            <script src="~/js/site.min.js" asp-append-version="true"></script>
        </environment>
```

Answer (score 11, accepted):

your url results in 404 error :

```
https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery.bootstrapvalidator/0.5.3/js/bootstr‌​apValidator.js
```

try this [link](https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap-validator/0.5.3/js/bootstrapValidator.js)  :

```
https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap-validator/0.5.3/js/bootstrapValidator.js
```

Answer (score 1):

From [here thanks shehary](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/twitter-bootstrap-stackoverflow/ZzgGDJeQA5Y)

> TypeError: $(…).... is not a function

is a common error where

1. jQuery library not included at all in the document
2. Specific JS library (in this case bootstrapvalidator.js) placed
   above jQuery library or not included at all in the document.
3. When following the most common practice to put all JS libraries in
   footer and then place custom scripts somewhere inside the page above
   all JS libraries and those custom script(s) not
   $(document).ready(function(){ });

Best and most common practice using JS libraries is in following order

1. JQuery lib (Always comes first)
2. Framework lib (e.g bootstrap, foundation etc)
3. Any other additional JS libraries

Custom script lib (Put all custom scripts here and make sure they are DOM ready and this file always placed as last file)

Try to place the CSS and JS in following order in  section

```
<head>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="//maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/css/bootstrap.css"/>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery.bootstrapvalidator/0.5.3/css/bootstrapValidator.css"/>
    <!---- AnyOther custom stylesheets ---->
    <script type="text/javascript" src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.0/jquery.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="//maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/js/bootstrap.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery.bootstrapvalidator/0.5.3/js/bootstrapValidator.js"></script>
    <!---- Any
```

Comment: I have the same problem as @Shahzeb. Even if I put them in this order (which look to be logical order), still doesn't work.

Comment: This happens when u have include of files as headers . Must be careful where are u using them

Answer (score 1):

Add this:

```
    <script type="text/javascript" src="http://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery.bootstrapvalidator/0.5.3/js/bootstrapValidator.min.js"> </script>
```

after your jquery library and framework librery (bootstrap, etc)

so you will have something like this:

```
 <script src="Scripts/jquery-1.9.1.js"></script>
    <script src="Scripts/jquery-1.9.1.min.js"></script>
    <script src="Scripts/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
    <script src="Scripts/bootstrap.js"></script>
<%-- here you may add another scripts you have...  --%>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="http://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery.bootstrapvalidator/0.5.3/js/bootstrapValidator.min.js"> </script>
```